# Using WebClient with block() and RestTemplate is same?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient, spring-resttemplate

> from what I understand about Web Client is it's non blocking meaning
> the client does not need to wait till the response arrives and can do
> other tasks parallelly  But then using block() in Web Client supports
> requests synchronously is there any  slightest performance advantage
> when using Web client with block vs using Rest Template or both are same
> Basically if I have to use Web Client with block, then its better to
> still stick with Rest Template?

Answer (score 1):

`RestTemplate` is in maintenance mode and Spring advises us to use `WebClient` instead, see [Javadocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html).

However, using `block()`, `WebClient` offers the same synchronous way of working as `RestTemplate` does.